# Golang: bytes.Buffer max buffer exceeded

Tags: go, minify

I'm trying to use [minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify/issues/13) library to bundle and minify all my JavaScripts and CSSs, minimum code:

```
js := bytes.Buffer{}
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
if L.Check(err, `File doesn't exists: `+fname) == nil {
  dat, err = min.MinifyBytes(`text/js`, dat)
  js.Write(dat) 
  js.WriteRune(';')
}
```

But that code failed with `err="max buffer exceeded"` when minifying [ace.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/ace.js) and [jquery.dataTables.js](http://datatables.net/download/) (>400 KB) is this `bytes.Buffer` problem? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to GoDoc.org](https://godoc.org/github.com/tdewolff/parse), that error is actually thrown from another package by that author .. `parse`.

The doc comment says that the input cannot be larger than 4KB in size. Your libraries appear to be much bigger than that.

Luckily, the `MaxBuf` variable is exported from that package .. so you should be able to put this line before that code to fix *that particular error*:

```
parse.MaxBuf = parse.MaxBuf * 2
```